# Authentication for static content in Play (2)

Tags: java, playframework

What's the simplest way to add an authentication/authorization layer on top of static content (namely assets) within Play 2.6.x?

Assume we have static content that is routed as such:

```
## auth login page
GET /index   
## static (single-path shell) served (assuming login attempt was authenticated)
GET  /console controllers.Foo.secureHTML(path="/public/html", file="console.html")
```

An the routed controller method looks like this:

@Inject 
private Assets assets;

```
public Result secureHTML(String path, String file) {
  if(auth()) {
    return assets.at(path + "/" + file);   <--- return This asset (when authenticated)
  } else {
    // redirect to Login page...
    return unauthorized();
  }
}
```

Notes:

1) the assets we're serving would be *internal* to the deployed .jar
2) we're using Java, but a proposed solution in Scala would be fine too

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those in search of an answer, here's the solution we come up with:

```
public class AuthLayer extends Controller {
   @Inject
   private Environment environment;

   private boolean auth() {
      // do something smart
      // for now....
      return true;
   }

   public Result html(String path, String file) {
      if(auth()) {
          return ok(environment.getFile(path + "/" + file));
      } else {
          // redirect to Login page...
          return redirect("/path/to/loginForm");
      }
   }
}
```